# USAGE OF MEINE LIEBE ON A GRAVE MARKER

Tags: usage

CAN *MEINE LIEBE* BE USED ON A GRAVE OF A MAN AND WIFE TO MEAN SOULMATE, DARLING, DEAREST, DEAR?

ANY OTHER SHORT TERMS OF ENDEARMENT IMPLYING BOTH ARE EXPRESSING THE SAME FEELING.

THANK YOU TO ALL WHO RESPOND.

ADDED:  THERE WILL BE A BANNER WITH WEDDING RINGS IN THE MIDDLE. ON ONE SIDE WOULD BE MEINE THE OTHER SIDE LIEBE.  HOPING TO SIGNIFY ONE OF THE ABOVE....CAN MEINE LIEBE BE NEUTRAL IN THIS CASE?

Comment: Why are you writing in all-caps?

Comment: HANDICAPPED AND LOSS OF SIGHT-MS

Comment: HELLO, I'VE ADDED MORE INFORMATION.

Comment: You should add the name (or the names) below  "Meine Liebe".

Comment: THANK YOU,   YOUR SUGGESTION IS VERY HELPFUL AND APPRECIATED.  I WILL BE LOSING MY FATHER SOON AND YOUR SUGGESTION HELPS ME TO HONOR HIM/THEM.

Comment: AND IT HELPS RECOGNIZE THEIR GERMAN HERITAGE THEY WERE PROUD OF.  I DID NOT WANT TO USE GERMAN WORDS WRONG OR INNAPROPRIATELY.

Comment: You could also choose "Liebe ist ewig" or "Liebe ist unsterblich". Both means love does not end, the first has focus on the endless love the second says love does not die. This would hold the focus to the couple and would have no connection to the people they left behind in this world.

Comment: ALLERLEIRAUH, THANK YOU.  VERY APPRECIATED ALSO.  THE EXPLANATION IS HELPFUL.

Comment: @Allerleirauh Your suggestion "Liebe ist ewig" is interesting because the symbol of wedding rings resembles the symbol for infinity.

Comment: @PaulFrost Then one could also choose "Liebe ist unendlich". "unendlich" means literally "has no end", would fit very good to the infinity symbol. But "ewig" is more like "eternal", has the positive point of view.

Comment: DUE TO 2 FAMILY MEMBERS RIGID ACADEMIC INTERPRETATION OF, MEINE LIEBE (ESPECIALLY) AND RIGID THOUGHTS OF WHAT THE MARKER SHOULD INCLUDE, GERMAN SAYINGS AND  WORDS WILL  NOT BE CONSIDERED BY MY FAMILY.  SAD TRULY.  I HAVE LEARNED FROM YOUR RECOMMENDATIONS, THANK YOU, ALL.......THIS THREAD IS COMPLETE

Answer (score 1):

The context is a bit sparse, but

> Hier liegt meine liebe (Name)

might well mean:

> Here lies my beloved (name)

assuming the husband chose the tombstone inscription.

Comment: "Meine Liebe" does not imply that the husband survived his wife.  It can be just the opposite.

Comment: The inscription seems to be "Meine [wedding rings symbol] Liebe". Probably there is a name below, but the OP does not give this information.

Answer (score 1):

It sure can.

It's a bit a question of who has erected the tombstone. The literal translation of "Meine Liebe" is "My Love" or "My Dearest".

Yet the context is a bit sparse to be sure whether that's what you look for. I'd expect that to be on the tombstone of one of the partners when the other is still alive. If you look for an engraving of a couple, for both, that is IMHO a bit strange. One would then expect usually something along the lines of "Geliebte Eltern und Großeltern". Yet there is a great deal of variety as it's a personal thing.

Answer (score 1):

Forgive me as I am new here if I don't answer correct or need to learn the ins and outs of navigating this site new to me.   If it helps , I can research the tombstones in the old church I still go to in Johnson MN, USA. Many have German sayings or writings on them from the original members of this German Lutheran church.

Comment: HELLO, VIC HOFFMAN, HI, I'M NEW ALSO. PLEASE EXCUSE THE LAG IN GETTING BACK TO YOU.  I APPRECIATE THE OFFER AND KIND GESTURE.  I WISH TO RESPECTFULLY AND WITH GRATITUDE DECLINE.

Comment: HELLO VIC HOFFMAN,  PLEASE SEE ABOVE WHAT I HAVE ADDED IN THE COMMENTS ABOUT MEINE LIEBE. (ALL THE WAY UP TOP)

Comment: Most welcome and best of luck.